# Derived Functors, Projection Formula and Base Change in the Derived $\infty$-Category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, stacks, higher-algebra

Let $X$ be a smooth stack and $\mathcal O_X$ the ring of smooth functions on $X$, i.e. for any smooth $M \to X$, $\mathcal O_X(M \to X) = C^\infty(M)$.

In HigherAlgebra, the derived category $\mathcal D(X)$ is defined to be the
differential graded nerve of $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal O_X)^\circ$, the full subcategory spanned by the fibrant objects (Note that $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal O_X)$ is Grothendieck abelian).

Are there good references for the theory of derived functors in this setting?

Is it known when projection formula and (flat) base change work?

Edit: Let me explain why I think that the second question is a sensible one to ask. (I must admit that I found these sources after I posted that question)

There are some rather general results for the unbounded derived category in 
[Spaltenstein](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1988__65_2/CM_1988__65_2_121_0/CM_1988__65_2_121_0.pdf). Propositions (6.18) and (6.20) prove base change and projection formula in the case of ringed spaces (given some finiteness-condition on the ring).

Closer and at the same time further from my setting (topological stacks, but only sheaves of abelian groups and the push-forward has to have finite cohomological dimension) is Lemma (6.5.7) in [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1459v2.pdf).

One of the applications I have in mind is proving that Fourier-Mukai transformations are closed under composition - the only proof I know relies on base change and the projection formula.

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth stack"? Differentiable stack, i.e. the stack of principal bundles for a Lie groupoid, or something else?

Comment: I mean a differentiable stack, i.e. a stack that has an atlas that is a submersion. (as in Heinloth's notes on differentiable stacks)

Comment: Ok, good (that's the same as a stack of principal bundles btw).

Comment: May I ask what your motivation is? Without knowing more info, I would guess that this is only a reasonable thing to study if the stack $X$ has an etale atlas, i.e. is an etale differentiable stack (basically an orbifold, but without separation conditions).

Comment: I edited the question to give a little more background and a concrete application.